# SelectedIndex not working when SelectedItem is bound to model source and ItemsSource bound to model options

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, picker

Any tips on this would be appreciated. I have set my picker's options in my view model and to save this selected option back to my DB, I have bound the SelectedItem to the field attribute within the object's model. However then when setting the default selected index, it doesn't work. Please help!

code

```
<Picker Grid.Column="2"
    Grid.Row="0"
    x:Name="myPicker"
    HeightRequest="40"
    WidthRequest="50"
    FontSize="14"
    Margin="0,15,0,110"
                   
    ItemsSource="{Binding BindingContext.UserOptions,  Source={x:Reference myPage }}"                                                                               
    SelectedItem="{Binding .UnitAmount }"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentSelectedIndex}"/>
```

code-behind

```
private int currentSelectedIndex = 0;
    public int CurrentSelectedIndex
    {
        get => currentSelectedIndex;
        set
        {
            currentSelectedIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentSelectedIndex));
        }
    }
```

Model

```
public void setupSelectedItem()
    {
        this.CurrentSelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    public int CurrentSelectedIndex { get; private set; } = 0;
```

`

Comment: Where is your model?  Why do you have a source specified for ItemsSource but not the other bound properties?

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your help. I have a view model for myPage as as well as a model for the data I am saving back to mongoDB... It's been tricky as this picker is help with a listview. First post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65672124/picker-itemsource-values-not-binding-in-a-xaml-listview/65673083#65673083

Comment: Your post needs to contain enough information to fully illustrate the problem.  Referring to code contained in other posts is not sufficient

Comment: Okay, what further information do you need?

Comment: "Where is your model?" - ie, post the code for your model

Comment: I've updated to include methods contained within my model, sorry I didn't think this part was the problem.

Comment: @Jason question has been updated - are you able to help on this?

Answer (score 0):

> **SelectedIndex** of type int, the index of the selected item, which
> defaults to -1.
>
> **SelectedItem** of type object, the selected item, which
> defaults to null.

You should not binding `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` at the same time. They did the same work and choose one will be ok.

```
<Picker Grid.Column="2"
    Grid.Row="0"
    x:Name="myPicker"
    HeightRequest="40"
    WidthRequest="50"
    FontSize="14"
    Margin="0,15,0,110"
                   
    ItemsSource="{Binding BindingContext.UserOptions,  Source={x:Reference myPage }}"                                                                               
    SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentSelectedIndex}"/>
```

If it still does not work,
I would like to know if `CurrentSelectedIndex` is a property of your `ViewModel` or a property of `UserOptions`?

Update, bind to SelectedItem:

ViewModel:

```
public class viewModel {

    List<string> UserOptions { get; set; }
    public string UnitAmount { get; set; }

    public viewModel()
    {
        //other codes

        setupSelectedItem();
    }

    public void setupSelectedItem()
    {
        this.UnitAmount = UserOptions[0];
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>

    <Picker Grid.Column="2"
        Grid.Row="0"
        x:Name="myPicker"
        HeightRequest="40"
        WidthRequest="50"
        FontSize="14"
        Margin="0,15,0,110"                   
        ItemsSource="{Binding BindingContext.UserOptions,  Source={x:Reference myPage }}"     
        SelectedItem="{Binding UnitAmount }"
        />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for your help. The only problem with this solution is that if I remove the SelectedItem reference to UnitAmount, then it wont save back to my model to be saved into my mongoDB. CurrentSelectedIndex is a property of my viewmodel and I'm happy for this to be hard coded as 0 so the first item is selected on load...

Comment: Then you can choose to remove "{Binding CurrentSelectedIndex}" and bind  SelectedItem="{Binding UnitAmount }" instead. Then  hard code the UnitAmount as the first element of your itemSourec at first. It will also select fist element.

Comment: Thanks Jack, please could you show a quick example of how to do that?

Comment: @Avatar 
Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Hi Jack, I add a range to my list as follows  listOptions.AddRange(unitAmounts); this.unitAmounts = listOptions[0]; I also tried this.unitAmounts[0] = listOptions[0]; but this didnt work either. I'm not sure whether it is possible due to the conflict of data bind loading to the list and the separate data bind to save the list to my mongodd model.

Comment: I don't see your viewmodel. UnitAmount should be the first element of the itemsource of picker.